# Dell U2312HM flickering

Tags: display

I bought a DELL U2312HM a year ago. I was actually preparing to buy 2 new monitors as this model.

It worked very well until a couple of hours. It started to flicker badly on the right side of the monitor. It has horizontal lines waves. The monitor's frequency is 60Hz at 1920x1080. When I do the colour test, the most affected colour is grey, followed by green and then white. I've switched between multiple computers with very different setups and all I get is flickering. I thought that maybe the display drivers are the problem, so I've reinstalled all of them again, but nothing got better.

I need to have good monitors because I have lots of work, especially this summer. What do you think? What's problem? And how can I fix it? It's urgent to me. Replacing it with something less capable would "kill" me. I still have warranty, but their service is crap. I'm not in the US.

Comment: So you have horizontal lines on half the monitor?  If thats the case then you have a hardware failure.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, those horizontal lines go from top to bottom. Thus they are called flickers, right? It's more like one third of the monitor.

Comment: The fact you have anything except a clean picture indicates a hardware problem.  You have ruled out the computer since the problem exists on multiple computers.  The monitor is defective.

Comment: So what should I do? I've never experienced a problem with any monitor.

Comment: Considering its defective I would get it replaced.  As the end user you won't be able to fix whats wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that the problem persists on multiple computers indicates wither a cable or monitor fault (assuming you took the cable to the other PCs).

The fact that it persists on the monitor colour test rules out cables leaving you with the fact that you have a hardware failure.

You still have warranty - so use it!  I knwo the service with some major manufacturers is bad - but this is your only real choice.. that or forget the warranty and purchase a new screen.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Interesting. The flickering disappeared after a few hours. Should I still use the warranty?

Comment: DEFINITELY!  If you don't and the flickering (or worse) re-appears just after the warranty expires - you'd be kicking yourself for ages.  If there is a change the kit is failing, its not fit for purpose!

Comment: Are the majority of monitors that bad quality as mine?

Comment: I have a pair of these and they are awesome... cant complain about them in the slightest: http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=uk&cs=ukdhs1&l=en&sku=842342

Answer (score -1):

It's hardware fault.

We bought a batch of six of these U2312HM monitors about a year ago (manufactured in June 2013), and 3 (so far) have failed in the last couple of months with that same fault down the right hand side.

It's a shame because they seemed really good value monitors otherwise.

Update: (just a small correction) We actually ordered 8 originally (not 6), and in the last week another one (the 4th so far) developed that same issue. Either way we've had 50% fail within a year.

Comment: It kind of scares me, because since I posted this question, my monitor started to work properly again, and now I can't go in service with it.

Answer (score -3):

I had same problem. I changed my VGA cable to the old type (having very thick insulation). So by changing the VGA cable with thick type, solves the problem.

Comment: I doubt this is an answer that would actually solve the OP's problem.